# Why was there a miniature bread on the ISS?

Tags: iss, food

In the NASA images and video library there is a image of a miniature bread floating in ISS node 1 (expedition 34 in 2013). Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any information on the experiment or general research this bread was part of (Google, Twitter, arXiv):

[image: View of miniature bread floating]

Source: https://images.nasa.gov/details-iss034e028521.html

So, why was there a miniature bread on ISS?

Comment: Without context, this picture is fantastically absurd.

Comment: "Why was there a miniature bread on the ISS?" For people to eat ;-) This looks like it might be delicious; zooming in, it looks perfect!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This article suggests it is just food: https://www.rbth.com/russian-kitchen/328572-russian-space-food-evolution

> Bread should be prepared quite differently, so that it does not
>   crumble and lasts a long time. The Russian Institute of the Bakery
>   Industry had to come up with solution for using the bread at the
>   International Space Station without the risk of crumbs getting into
>   the ventilation system. They came up with a miniature loaf - just big
>   enough for one bite. In texture and taste, this bread is virtually
>   indistinguishable from that which we eat on Earth.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting read! Makes a lot of sense. I just noticed that there is a whole blister full of mini-breads in the hand...

Comment: @MarcusBitzl One 'loaf' is 3 grams. There are 10 in the pack, so it's mere 30 grams of bread - so about as much as a single slice of normal bread. "Year in orbit" contains a [fragment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQ-f2wgZ6xo&index=4&list=PLS93_pp5BAdVE4JOFrZKwF6IO3DkD-g66) on production of these.