# Did astronaut Scott Kelly eat cake in space?

Tags: identify-this-object, astronaut-lifestyle, food, reduced-gravity-cooking

From what I understand and remember the first cookies baked in space were returned to Earth for testing and I think part of the reason that no cookies baked on the ISS's oven could be eaten is that they could make crumbs. Certainly the most bread-like product regularly consumed on the ISS are tortillas and in part this is because of their low *crumb coefficient*, and what bread is sent to space is bite-sized, reducing the *effective* crumb coefficient to nearly zero.

[image: tiny loaf of bread in space] click for larger, from [Why was there a miniature bread on the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32552/12102)

In CNN's new video [He spent 520 days in space. Hear his tips for coping with isolation](https://youtu.be/-Gsg_XPuaoQ) retired astronaut Scott Kelly recommends several thing that one can do to cope that he draws especially from his experience of an extended stay in the ISS, though one may have been more difficult than the other three:

- Follow a schedule
- Keep consistent bedtime
- Go outside
- Pursue a hobby

But what caught my eye is file footage of him about to eat what looks like chocolate cake or perhaps a brownie.

**Question:** Did astronaut Scott Kelly eat cake (or a brownie) in space? Was it tested for crumb generation and approved for spaceflight?

[image: Scott Kelly; surviving isolation in space] [image: screenshot of file footage of Scott Kelly eating chocolate cake or brownie in space]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know exactly what Kelly is eating there, but [brownies are on the ISS menu](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/stem-on-station/ditl_eating).

> Some foods can be eaten in their natural forms, such as brownies and fruit.

A good moist brownie in bite-sized pieces has a manageable crumb coefficient.

Comment: If they are like my brownies they are a bit gooey inside, very low crumb. I'll have to send them some.

Comment: "Crumb coefficient."  I'll have to add that to my list of statistically improbable phrases.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please share the list in the future